framer-motion animation isse when switching from `hidden` tab
I have the following motion.div component in one of my tabs:
 <motion.div
          className='relative flex flex-col gap-4'
          animate='visible'
          initial='hidden'
          variants={{
            hidden: { opacity: 0 },
            visible: {
              opacity: 1,
              transition: {
                staggerChildren: 0.15,
                delayChildren: 0,
              },
            },
          }}
        >
          <AnimatePresence initial={true} mode='wait'>
            <LayoutGroup>
              {data
                ?.filter((el) => !hiddenIds.includes(el.id))
                .map((homework) => (
                  <motion.div
                    layout
                    key={homework.id}
                    variants={{
                      hidden: { opacity: 0, x: 20 },
                      visible: {
                        opacity: 1,
                        x: 0,
                      },
                    }}
                    exit={{ opacity: 0, x: 20 }}
                  >
                    <HomeworkCard
                      key={homework.id}
                      homework={homework}
                      showUserActions={showUserActions}
                      showTeacherActions={showTeacherActions}
                      onHide={() => setHiddenIds([...hiddenIds, homework.id])}
                    />
                  </motion.div>
                ))}
            </LayoutGroup>
          </AnimatePresence>
        </motion.div>

When the tab opens, it works fine and:

Elements animate nicely one after one
When I remove an element, other elements nicely change their position.

The problem is when I switch to another tab and the above components is wrapped in display: none. When I switch back, all the elements animates their position from top-left corner to the destination one - how  can I prevent it from happening and simply leave the state from before switching tabs?
